# Error con decimales en tabla (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una función en JavaScript pero estoy atascado en una parte. Tengo la siguiente tabla que se observa abajo en la foto en el que tiene 3 columnas: Tipo de Combustible, En tanque de Superficie, En tanques enterrados. En las columnas "En tanque de Superficie" y "En tanques enterrados" se incluyen cantidades como enteros o decimales y aquí es donde llega mi problema. Yo puedo añadir un valor entero (por ejemplo 2) y un valor con decimales (por ejemplo 2,5), pero cuando añado un valor con decimales con punto (por ejemplo 2.5) me lo coge como 25, debiendo ser 2,5, es decir, si introduzco una cantidad entera o con valor decimal con coma (2,5) funciona y se añade bien en la tabla, pero si añado un valor con punto no me lo coge bien. Para ello estoy intentando reemplazar el punto por la coma y que así me lo muestre bien en la tabla, pero sigue sin cogermelo bien. Adjunto mí código donde estoy realizando las pruebas:

```
function formatNmb(campo, numeroMaximoEnteros, numeroDecimales)
{
if (campo.value == '')
    return;
if (campo.readOnly == true)
    return;
// Al obtener el numero, elimina primero los posibles '.' (de anteriores
// formateos, por ejemplo)
campo.value = campo.value.replace(/\./gi, '');
// Cambia la coma por un punto y asi poder parsearlo.
campo.value = campo.value.replace(/\,/gi, '.');

// miramos la parte entera del numero y la comparamos con el parametro
// numeroMaximosEnteros
if (campo.value.indexOf('.') != -1)
{
    if (campo.value.indexOf('.') == 0)
    {
        campo.value = "0";
        entero = "0";
    }
//..........................................
//..........................................
```

En la primera fila de la tabla se han añadido valores con puntos (5.5), pero me los muestra como 55 y la siguiente fila 2,5 me lo muestra bien, ¿estaría bien lo del reemplazo? Aunque no me falla utilizando el "replace".

[image: Tabla Imagen de prueba]

Comment: El problema está en que la línea con el código `campo.value = campo.value.replace(/\./gi, '')` elimina el punto de la cadena ingresada transformando el número ingresado en un entero. El separador de decimales de JavaScript es el punto. Si quiseras mostrar los números con otro formato, te recomiendo que utilices el objeto [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat)

Comment: Sería eliminar la línea que me has comentado? o como sería?                                                                      
        Y el ejemplo segundo que me has comentado, seria así?campo.value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(numeroDecimales).

Answer (score 0):

**esto te podria ayudar a validar mejor:**

1. la funcion `typeof()` devuelve el tipo del parametro pasado
2. la funcion `parseFloat` hace un cast a flotante
3. la funcion `replace()` remplaza una cadena por otra
4. la funcion `toFixed()` convierte a flotante, recibe como argumento la
   cantidad de decimales requeridos

```js
//recibimos un arreglo de datos
function r(n){
  // creamos una variable llamada suma
  let sum=0;
  //iteramos el arreglo
  for(x of n){
  // si el tipo es string remplaza , por . combierte a float y lo suma si no solo lo suma
    typeof(x) == "string"?sum+=parseFloat(x.replace(",",".")): sum+=x;
  }
  //retorna la suma
  return sum.toFixed(2);
}
var number=[2,"2,5",2.5];
console.log(r(number))
```

si quieres solo validar 1 numero a la vez

```js
var r=(n)=>{ return typeof(n) == "string"? parseFloat(n.replace(",",".")).toFixed(2):n.toFixed(2);}

console.log(r("2,2"))
console.log(r(2,2))
```